# I do not understand how this JS code is working; how are these two lines being returned?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, boolean-expression

```js
let specificSuffix = function(words, suffix) {
  if (!Array.isArray(words)) {
    return [];
  }
  return words.filter(function(word) {
    return word.endsWith(suffix)
  });
}

console.log(specificSuffix(['family', 'hound', 'catalyst', 'fly', 'timidly', 'bond'], 'ly'));
// [ 'family', 'fly', 'timidly' ]
console.log(specificSuffix(['simplicity', 'computer', 'felicity'], 'ily'));
// [ ]
```

I'm confused specifically about:

```
return words.filter(function(word) {
  return word.endsWith(suffix)
});
```

How am I returning both of these things? The filter is saying, return this empty new array, fill it with the words that endWith the suffix... (I think)

It's really just the two returns that are throwing me. How does this work?

Comment: Note that the second `return` is inside a **separate function**, specifically the callback passed to `.filter()`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if we extract the variable `result` the code will make more sense?

```
const specificSuffix = function(words, suffix) {
  if (!Array.isArray(words)) return [];

  const result = words.filter(function(word) {
    return word.endsWith(suffix)
  });

  return result;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this makes the most sense to me. I appreciate you showing me an alternative method, it helped me make complete sense of it this way, and now I know 2 ways! Thanks a bunch. 
Happy 2/22/22 Tuesday; remember to get some tacos today! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return words.filter(function(word){
 return word.endsWith(suffix)
  });
```

The outer return returns the result of [`words.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Inside the `filter()` function we have to pass a callback. So the `return` inside is for that callback. In short you have to return true/false, based on a condition inside the filter callback.